# Javascript compare two tables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with comparing two tables that presents like this:

```
table A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
table B = [2, 4]
```

I need to check if the table A contains numbers from table B and to put it in another array:

Expected output:

```
table C = [false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Tried a few things but nothing works out for me.
The `table.includes` method gives me following output

```
let isAdded = [];
  allObjectivesArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (allObjectivesArray.includes(reducedArr[0][element - 1])) 
isAdded.push(true);
    else isAdded.push(false);
```

});

// That is the output of above
isAdded = [true, true, false, false, false, false, false]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so we can help you to debug it. Remember that SO is here to help you to debug code, not to write it for you.

Comment: Sure, just edited the code but Mina gave me the clue already! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the array `a` and check in the `callback` if each item exists in the array `b` with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function, if exists `includes` will return `true` if not will return `false`

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const b = [2, 4];

const result = a.map(i => b.includes(i))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Damn, thank you! I do not really know why i wanted to make it in such a strange way... Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
tableA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
tableB = [2, 4];

let tableC = tableA.map((el) => 
  tableB.indexOf(el) != -1
);

console.log(tableC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tableA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const tableB = [2, 4]

const fun =(ar, refAr)=>{
const booleanSet = ar.map((e, i) => refAr.includes(e))
console.log(booleanSet)
}
fun(tableA ,tableB)
```